# QIcon blurred on Retina iPad Air

Tags: ios, qt, retina, qicon

I am currently developing an app for iOS with QT 5.7. I am using some buttons which have an QIcon applied. QIcon loads a *.png file and it is assigned to the pushbutton via QIcon::pixmap().
While this is nice looking on my iMac (without retina) on my iPAD the icons look always blurred like scaled up. Tried different sizes for the *.png-file, different sizes for setIconSize etc. but nothing helps.
This is basically my code where I load the file:

```
ui->pushButtonAdd->setIcon( QIcon( QPixmap(":pencil64.png") ) );
ui->pushButtonAdd->setIconSize( QSize(32, 32) );
ui->pushButtonAdd->setFixedSize( 100, 100 );
```

Does anybody have an idea what is going wrong?

Raphael

Comment: `Qt::AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps`

Comment: Thanks. That is the solution! It is working now.